# Moving and resizing from storage

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I'm trying to get an image or images and move from one folder to another, and with this resize the image using Intervention, but is not working.

Gives me a error of:

> ErrorException  : file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

I guess I'm not applying right my code.

Code:

```
$imageName = Storage::disk('public')->exists('media/products/'.$product[0].'.jpg') ? $product[0].".jpg" : $product[0].".png" ;

$grabImage = Storage::get('public/media/products/'.$imageName);

Image::make($grabImage)->resize(400, 400)->save( public_path("media/products/thumbs/" . $grabImage ) );
```

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857080/file-exists-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-path-string-given

Comment: First update `$grabImage = Storage::disk('public')->get('media/products/'.$imageName);`

Comment: Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException  : Can't write image data to path